# Why won't Gtk's button_press_event receive single left clicks?

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtkmm

I am trying to set up an add-tab button in a Gtk::Notebook (gtkmm). I am doing this by drawing a pixmap to a calculated position -- that works just fine. However, when trying to receive events for it, I cannot pick up a single left click. Single middle and single right give both press and release events, and double left gives just a press event, but single left doesn't register anything. How can I properly receive events?

Comment: Are you trying to catch the click-event for the button or for the image? The left-click might be caught by the button and never propagated to the image, the right click probably just passed on.

Comment: There is no button -- the image is over the top of the blank space to the right of the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you draw your image in a `GtkEventBox`?

Comment: The reason that I am manually drawing the image is because it needs to be on top of another widget. Is there an easy way to put an EventBox at a specific pixel location?

Comment: That would BE a GtkFixed widget.